# R ddply/apply string split accessing all data frames columns in a list

Tags: r

I have of a set of data frames of this following types in a list `salesList`:

```
   X.                                         Game       Owners.before          Owners.after     Sales Increase  Price Max.discount Userscore..Metascore.
1  14 Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare - Multiplayer   1,617,539 ±75,027  6,467,189 ±63,403 4,849,650  299.82% $59.99 25% ($44.99)             N/A (78%)
2  63                           Grand Theft Auto V                0 ±0  2,077,609 ±36,281 2,077,609       0% $59.99  0% ($59.99)             83% (96%)
3  59                       Dungeon of the Endless     194,543 ±26,101  2,173,362 ±37,100 1,978,819 1017.16% $11.99  50% ($6.49)             90% (79%)
4 157                      DiRT 3 Complete Edition     298,664 ±32,332    976,615 ±24,933   677,951  226.99% $29.99 20% ($23.99)             89% (86%)
5   1             Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 12,256,215 ±201,631 12,671,726 ±87,533   415,511    3.39% $14.99  0% ($14.99)             93% (83%)
6 473                              Killing Floor 2                0 ±0    279,056 ±13,348   279,056       0% $29.99  0% ($29.99)             83% (N/A)
```

I want to apply the following instructions - wrote for a single data frame - to all the data frames in the list using ddply or apply:

```
owners.after <- strsplit(sales$Owners.after, split=" ±")
sales$owners.after.est <- sapply(owners.after, function(i) i[1])
sales$owners.after.band <- sapply(owners.after, function(i) i[2])
owners.before <- strsplit(sales$Owners.before, split=" ±")
sales$owners.before.est <- sapply(owners.before, function(i) i[1])
sales$owners.before.band <- sapply(owners.before, function(i) i[2])
```

The problem is about accessing each column named `Owners.after` and `Owners.before` in the list and split the data.

Comment: You can use `sales[c("owners.after.est", "owners.after.band")] <- do.call(rbind, owner.after)` and the same for `owners.before`.   Also, can loop over both the columns and do the `strsplit`

Comment: How do you access each column of `Owners.before` in `salesList` to apply `strsplit`?

Comment: It is the same as above i.e. `sales[c("owners.before.est", "owners.before.band")] <- do.call(rbind, owners.before)`